# Как передать ссылку на массив объектов в другой объект?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет

Есть класс (пусть будет А), в нём есть массив

```
Socket connectionlist[] = new Socket[100];
```

В этом же классе создаётся много объектов класса Б. Класс Б наследует класс Thread и переопределяет метод run(). Создается много объектов этого класса и столько же потоков.

Вопрос такой - могу ли я в каждый объект передать ссылку (именно ссылку,а не копию, на массив со всеми сокетами)?

Для простоты понимания - это чатсервер и у него есть главный поток, который ждет подключений и по 1 потоку на каждого киента, которые ждут сообщений и рассылают их остальным. Но я не могу додуматься как в потоке получить доступ к другим сокетам.

Comment: разумеется, connectionlist можно передавать в экземпляры в класса Б (в конструктор или методы).. другое дело как с этим листом работать с учетом много поточности